# How to search a text in a Windows form (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, forms, search, text, properties

I'm looking for a form in a company program, the only clues I have are the texts that are displayed in the form. I tried using ctrl+shift+f to search for all clues but did not find any.

Note: the code comments regarding the location of the form is that the form is an executable command.

I'm having a hard time looking for it, please help.

Comment: You could try some external tool like AstroGrep to find the file containing the text.

Comment: When you use ctrl+shift+f, did you change the "Look in" drop-down to "Entire solution"?

If there is text anywhere on a form, it should show up with that search. 

Unless that form does not exist in said solution and is called externally.